# unbind onclick event for 'a' inside a div with onclick event

Tags: jquery, onclick

html:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="desc">desc</div>
<a href="foo.php">foo</a>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#container').click(function(){
    ...
    my_function();
    ...
});
```

This works when the user click inside container except for the a tag.

If the user click a tag, the click event fires.  However, I want to disable self-defined click function for a tag. That is, link to the page without the onlick event.

This doesn't work:

```
$('#container :not(a)').click();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly: You want to disable the click handler defined for `#container` if the link is clicked? Or do you want to prevent the browser from following the link?

Comment: I want to disable the click handler defined to #container when a tag is clicked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if the event originates from the `a` tag, like so

```
$('#container').click(function(e){
    if ($(e.target).is('a')) return;
    ...
    my_function();
    ...
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. $(this).is('a') returns false even if I click a tag . Here is the live example: http://jsfiddle.net/cfBrm/1/

Comment: @benck, realized that just after I added this answer. I edited that line, check again. **Edit**: here http://jsfiddle.net/cfBrm/2/

Comment: This solution only works if the hyperlink uses text as the anchor. If an image is used, the target is "object HTMLImageElement".  (I posted alternate solution.)

Comment: @JamesMoberg, true. But this solution does work when there are `a` tags dynamically added to `#container` later on. The solution you provided doesn't handle this. It depends on the situation in the end I guess.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you want to prevent the default click event for `A` tags firing - use:

```
$('#container a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Edit**

To prevent your event from firing if the user clicks a link:

```
$('#container').click(function(e) {
  if(e.target.tagName !== 'A') {
    my_function();
  }
});
```

Comment: and use `e.preventDefault();` instead of `return false;` because you do want the click to bubble to the parent `<div>`

Comment: The OP did not specify he wanted to prevent the default action for the `a` tag, just that the event handler for `#container` shouldn't be fired.

Comment: I want to disable self-defined event, not default event.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a click event handler to your links to tell them to stop event bubbling after their own handler executes:

```
$("#container a").click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
})
```

*The other solutions won't work with hyperlinks using images as an anchor.  (target=object HTMLImageElement & tagName=DIV)*